# paste0 within a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop

What I'd like to obtain is a dataset like this:

```
ID var
1  t0
1  t1
1  t2
2  t0
2  t1
2  t2
```

where t restart from 0 for each ID.

If I use:

```
all <- data.frame(ID=character(),var=numeric())

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 0:3) {
    df <- data.frame(matrix(c(rep(i,3),paste0("t",j)), byrow = F, ncol = 2, nrow = 6))
    all <- rbind(all,df) 
  }
}
```

there is something clearly wrong.
How can I manage it?

Comment: you don't need the inner-loop or the matrix to dataframe cohercion Try this: `j = 0:2;
for (i in 1:2) {
  df <- data.frame(ID = rep(i,3),
                   var = paste0("t",j))
  all <- rbind(all,df) 
};`

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Change the line marked ## as shown.

```
all <- data.frame(ID=character(),var=numeric())

for (i in 1:2) {
  for (j in 0:3) {
    df <- data.frame(ID = i, var = paste0("t", j))  ##
    all <- rbind(all,df) 
  }
}
```

**2)** or use `expand.grid`

```
expand.grid(var = paste0("t", 0:3), ID = 1:2)[2:1]
```

**3)** Another possibility is `crossing` from the tidyr package:

```
library(tidyr)
crossing(ID = 1:2, var = paste0("t", 0:3))
```

**4)** there are a number of packages that support python and haskell like comprehensions (comprehenr, eList, listcompr).  Using the first:

```
library(comprehenr)
to_df(for(i in 1:2) for(j in 0:3) list(ID = i, var = paste0("t", j)))
```

Also note comments below this answer for an additional option.

Comment: One more is `CJ(ID = 1:2, var = paste0("t", 0:3))` from `data.table`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend against building a `data.frame` iteratively like that: it works as expected initially, but as it grows larger, it starts to get much slower, quickly (because every time you add a row, it makes a complete copy of *all* rows). Better to form a list of frames, and then combine them once. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/24376207/3358227.

To build your frame, here are a couple of ways.

1. Build it that way from the start, all are groups of three:

   ```r
   data.frame(ID = rep(seq_len(3), each = 3), var = paste0("t", rep(seq_len(3) - 1, times = 3)))
   #   ID var
   # 1  1  t0
   # 2  1  t1
   # 3  1  t2
   # 4  2  t0
   # 5  2  t1
   # 6  2  t2
   # 7  3  t0
   # 8  3  t1
   # 9  3  t2
   ```
2. If your data already exists and you just want to add the `var` field:

   ```r
   dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(seq_len(3), each = 3))
   dat$var <- paste0("t", ave(dat$ID, dat$ID, FUN = seq_along) - 1)
   ```

Comment: Thanks, I'd be faster but in my real data the ID variable it is not just 1,2,etc, so I need the foor loop at least for the i.

Comment: In your real data, you build a `data.frame` from scratch with arbitrary numbers? If you're doing it in a `for` loop, then you must know the IDs and each length beforehand, in which case you don't need a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using the newest version (0.3.0) of the [listcompr](https://github.com/patrickroocks/listcompr) package, you can use `{}` brackets within characters as placeholders for variables. For instance `"t{j}"` is evaluated to `"t1", "t2", ...` for `j = 1, 2, ...`.

Your example data set can be created using `gen.data.frame` from the listcompr package:

```
> library(listcompr)
> gen.data.frame(c(ID = i, var = "t{j}"), j = 0:2, i = 1:2)
  ID var
1  1  t0
2  1  t1
3  1  t2
4  2  t0
5  2  t1
6  2  t2
```